# eslint indent and @typescript-eslint/indent conflict

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, eslint

So I'm using eslint and prettier on a TS express app. I want to set tab width to 4, but it seems the base eslint and the typescript eslint are in conflict.

This is what it gives me for the same line:

[image]

This is my eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": "standard-with-typescript",
    "overrides": [],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "project": "tsconfig.json"
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 4],
        "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "endOfLine": "auto" }]
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": ["prettier"]
}
```

This is my prettierrc.json:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "printWidth": 120,
  "semi": false,
  "tabWidth": 4
}
```

Any idea how to resolve it so I can just have 4 spaces to a tab?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using prettier and eslint, you should use the prettier eslint configuration. It will disable every style-only eslint rule. It should be ok, since styles would be left for prettier to format. See [the docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html) for more info on this.

Since you have the prettier plugin installed, you can change your extends line to this and it should be enough:

```
"extends": ["standard-with-typescript", "plugin:prettier/recommended"]
```